# How to make Spray Json throw exception when it sees extra fields?

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

For example suppose I have

```
case class Test(a: String, b: String)
...
implicit val testFormat = jsonFormat2(Test.apply)
```

and a json with an extra `c` field:

```
val test = "{\"a\": \"A\", \"b\": \"B\", \"c\": \"C\"}"
```

then I want to find a way (config/param/whatever) to make the following line throw and exception:

```
test.parseJson.convertTo[Test]
```

It's very hard to work this out from reading the source code and github documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything in the library that provides that functionality, so I created a wrapper that does a quick check on the number of fields present before delegating the read call to the supplied formatter.

```
case class StrictRootFormat[T](format: RootJsonFormat[T], size: Int) extends RootJsonFormat[T] {

  def read(json: JsValue): T = {
    if(json.asJsObject.fields.size > size) deserializationError("JSON has too many fields: \n " + json.toString())
    else format.read(json)
  }

  def write(obj: T): JsValue = format.write(obj)

}
```

Usage:

```
implicit val testFormat = StrictRootFormat(jsonFormat2(Test.apply), 2)
```

You could enhance the read implementation so that you don't need to supply the "size" argument.

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the answer, not quite what we need, since we could have some `Option`al fields missing and end up with the exact same size.  Nevertheless I think I could edit it to work - by supplying the `ClassTag` we can use `productIterator.toSet`.  Ideally I'd also like to ensure this also works with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33367983/how-to-parse-json-with-spray-json-that-uses-snake-case-underscore-notation-ins/33367984#33367984