# How to parse json with spray json that uses snake case (underscore notation) instead of camel case

Tags: json, scala, spray, spray-json

How to parse json with spray json that uses snake case (underscore notation) instead of camel case?

E.g.

```
case class Test(subjectDescription: String)
"{\"subject_description\":\"Medicine\"}".parseJson.convertTo[Test]
```

should work and not throw exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is taken from https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/spray-user/KsPIqWDK0AY/HcanflgRzMcJ. Putting it on SO since the SEO is better.

```
/**
 * A custom version of the Spray DefaultJsonProtocol with a modified field naming strategy
 */
trait SnakifiedSprayJsonSupport extends DefaultJsonProtocol {
  import reflect._

  /**
   * This is the most important piece of code in this object!
   * It overrides the default naming scheme used by spray-json and replaces it with a scheme that turns camelcased
   * names into snakified names (i.e. using underscores as word separators).
   */
  override protected def extractFieldNames(classTag: ClassTag[_]) = {
    import java.util.Locale

    def snakify(name: String) = PASS2.replaceAllIn(PASS1.replaceAllIn(name, REPLACEMENT), REPLACEMENT).toLowerCase(Locale.US)

    super.extractFieldNames(classTag).map { snakify(_) }
  }

  private val PASS1 = """([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])""".r
  private val PASS2 = """([a-z\d])([A-Z])""".r
  private val REPLACEMENT = "$1_$2"
}

object SnakifiedSprayJsonSupport extends SnakifiedSprayJsonSupport

import SnakifiedSprayJsonSupport._

object MyJsonProtocol extends SnakifiedSprayJsonSupport {
  implicit val testFormat = jsonFormat1(Test.apply)
}
```

Comment: def extractFieldNames() overrides nothing... What's the version of spray-json used here?

Comment: @ÁkosVandra Erm 1.3.1 or earlier.

Comment: yeah confirm this works. We actually have hit an unrelated scalac bug with implicit imports.

Answer (score 7):

Like this:

```
case class Test(subjectDescription: String)
implicit val testFormat = jsonFormat(Test.apply, "subject_description")
"{\"subject_description\":\"Medicine\"}".parseJson.convertTo[Test]
```

The trick here is `jsonFormat` function takes string arguments for json object keys.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd prefer an automatic approach.  We have dozens of classes each with dozens of fields.